Unlink Office 2013 retail from wrong Microsoft account
I bought several Microsoft Office 2013, retail version from a seller confirming they are no longer in use. Such licenses are transferable.
However, to check that the licenses were working, their IT guy had the wrong idea to create a fresh "licenses" Microsoft account where he "activated" the licenses, a priori without downloading/installing the software.
The credentials (username / password) to that account were transfered to me, so that I can log in it.
I can see that the two licences are registered there.
I believe the softwares were not installed (apart from a possible copy), because there are still links suggesting to install it.
However, I don't want the software that I purchased being linked to that account.
Like at minute 3:20 from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ed2NhtCqedk ,
I expected to find after login, some "Deactivate install" link. But there is none.
When trying to activate the licenses with my own account, Microsoft's server answer that the number of activations has been exceeded, and only offers phone activation.
As the legal owner of these second hand Office 2013 licenses, what should I do?

You will have to contact Microsoft licensing as Office 2013 is NOT linked to a Microsoft account that integration didn’t happen until Office 2016. You will notice this fact if you rewatch the video, the announcer, was using Office 2016 not Office 2013

Why does the title of this question ask about Office 2023 instead of Office 2013? I am voting to close this question until its details are clarified.

@Ramhound: Thank you. Yes, the video shows Office 2016. With Office 2013, there is kind of partial account linking. Once activated, you can use it without connecting. However, activating it without connecting to an account seems impossible nowadays (unless cheating), since the usual activation servers are no longer found at step 3 of the activation.
Sorry for the error in the title, it was a typo, likely because I was tired. It was corrected.

You can always activate by phone

I still want to point out that the video isn’t relevant. You cannot log into a Microsoft account into Office 2013 like you can with Office 2016+
